# Load Image into map Marker using android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to add bitmap to google map marker icon.

Below is my code to add image to marker icon. Application is crashing because of bitmap size

Error :  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Textures with dimensions4096x8192 are larger than  the maximum supported size 4096x4096

```html
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
        String imageType=options.outMimeType;
        if(imageWidth > imageHeight) {
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,10,10);//if landscape
        } else{
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,10,10);//if portrait
        }
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;


        Bitmap  mapbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/TAG_IMG_25.2571724_55.2994563.jpg", options);

latLng=new LatLng(25.254376, 55.2973058);

marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title(_title)
            .snippet("dubai")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mapbitmap)));
```

```html
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Comment: At which line does the error occur?

Comment: on adding the bitmap to marker .icon

Comment: I think `calculateInSampleSize()` returns 1 in your case, can you confirm this? You use `int imageHeight = options.outHeight;` directly after initializing `options`. Looks like you're missing the code which actually reads the image dimensions into `options`.

Answer (score -1):

Answer is in your question itself.

```
Textures with dimensions4096x8192 are larger than the maximum supported size 4096x4096
```

So you must reduce the image size below 4096x4096 using any image editors such as Photoshop.

if you are not familiar , Here is a [tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/resize-image.html).

Comment: This is not a suitable solution when using, e.g., user-supplied images, taken with the device camera.

Comment: Would creating the Bitmap (or recreating it in this instance) with [setting the width and height](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.util.DisplayMetrics, int, int, android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)) be more appropriate to not have the said exception?